# debian testing hangs on wakeup from s2disk / hibernate

Tags: debian, kernel, hibernate, sleep

My machine (ThinkPad x230) hangs on wake up from `s2disk` <del>or s2ram</del> after a recent `aptitude safe-upgrade`.<sup>†</sup> The hang looks like a blank screen with a blinking cursor in the upper right after `loading data pages` completes.

Confirmed the same behavior after `sudo hibernate`, `sudo pm-hibernate`, and `echo disk | sudo tee /sys/power/state`.

I am on Debian testing, kernel 4.0.0-2-rt-amd64. Not sure where to go from here. Searching on Google produces many old results. Dump of `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` [here](http://paste.debian.net/287891/).

<sup>† Confirmed `s2ram` works as intended on wake up from suspend. `s2disk` still broken.</sup>

Comment: Have you tried [TuxOnIce](http://tuxonice.nigelcunningham.com.au/) yet???  That's what I use whenever Debian-derivatives don't work OOTB.  (I'm running Ubuntu).  If that works, drop me a note and I'll convert it to an answer...

Comment: I'd rather not patch my own kernel w/TuxOnIce

Comment: Patch the kernel?  Debian should work with the Ubuntu PPA...

Comment: TuxOnIce is a kernel patch. It is not advised to use Ubuntu PPAs for Debian.

Comment: OK...  I learnt something.

Comment: I have the same problem on dell latitude E7440 and debian testing. it started after the upgrade to kernel 4. I am now on kernel  4.1.0-2-amd64.

Comment: Roll back to the previous version of the kernel. See my updates in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Found a solution that works:</s>

1. `sudo blkid` and copy your swap UUID to clipboard
2. `sudo vim /boot/grub/menu.lst`, search for `resume=` and add `resume=UUID=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx`
3. update grub with `sudo update-grub`

That worked once and never again. Still looking.

**Update:** My problems went away once I switched from Linux kernel 4.0.0-2-rt-amd64 to 4.1.0-2-amd64. If you are experiencing a similar issue, first make sure you are not using the RT kernel without a good reason and second either upgrade or downgrade the kernel to see if that resolves the issue. Marking  as solved.